# How to remove white blank space between 2 columns of images?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm ploting 2 columns of images:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(10, 2, figsize=(50, 50))

axs[0, 0].imshow(a[0].reshape(224, 224, 3).astype(np.uint8))
axs[0, 0].set_axis_off()
axs[0, 1].imshow(a[0].reshape(224, 224, 3).astype(np.uint8))
axs[0, 1].set_axis_off()
    
for row in range (1, 10):
    axs[row, 0].imshow(b[row].reshape(224, 224, 3).astype(np.uint8))
    axs[row, 0].set_axis_off()
    
    axs[row, 1].imshow(b[row].reshape(224, 224, 3).astype(np.uint8))    
    axs[row, 1].set_axis_off()
```

I'm getting:

[image]

How can we compact the plot ? I want that the 2 columns will be display without the big white space in the middle ?

I have tried to use `tight_layout` but didn't get any improvment

Comment: If you don't want to deform the images, you need to narrow the width of the figsize. Or usr many more columns of subplots

Comment: There is also axes grid:  https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axes_grid1/simple_axesgrid.html

Answer (score 0):

Change your values for figsize(), at the moment they are a square i.e. 50x50, try 25x50 and other values until you are happy.